# Child not receiving parents props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I can't log the text in my `child` component, which should be passed from the `parent`. Can someone clear this up for me? I checked threads already but didn't find a solution.

Parent

```
import { Header } from '../components'

export default () => {
  const [baselineText, setBaselineText] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setBaselineText('This the ABOUT page')
  }, [])

  return <Header text={baselineText} />
    }
```

Child

```
export default () => {
  const handleText = (text) => {
    console.log(text)
  }
  handleText()

  return <header text={handleText}></header>
}
```

Comment: `text={handleText}` - what do you expect to happen here? You also need to receive the props object in the child component: `export default (props) => {` and then you can access the prop: `props.text`

Comment: when I `console.log(props.text)` in `child` I still get `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the `props` or destruct it. Like this

```
export default ({ text }) => {
  console.log(text);
  return <header text={text}></header>
}
```

Comment: Keep getting `undefined` ... I totally don't get it

Comment: can you check whether your `baselineText` is showing any value? In your `useEffect` after setting its value, log it to console and inside the array write `[baselineText]`. If it still shows `undefined` then please initialise `useState("")`.

Comment: This wont work since the set will not be executed then no? Because it will wait for `baselineText` to change